# Access Parent View Ids from manually inflated views using Data Binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have a Linear Layout where I am inflating views at runtime. The View which contains `LinearLayout` also has a `RadioGroup`. The view I am inflating has an `EditText` whose visibility depends on `RadioGroup`'s checked item. But, I am unable to access it using data-binding.

My view files are like below:

**content_main.xml:**

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_type"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/btn_1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/btn_1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/btn_2" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/btn_3" />

        </RadioGroup>

        ...

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And the layout xml I am inflating in `container` has an `EditText` like this:

**list_item_content_main.xml**

```
       ...
       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:visibility="@{btn3.checked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"  <!-- This line -->
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />
        ...
```

The compilation fails due to `radioType` not found in the variable list.

How can I reference `radio_type` element from the inflated layout file so that I can set the visibility of `EditText` by making use of data-binding?

Comment: what `variable list` do you mean?

Comment: Variables defined in the <data> part of the data binding layout file. As the radio type of btn3 is not in the layout file it is not compiling.

Comment: so you should use `DataBindingUtil` for things like that, see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#binding_data

Comment: Yes i am inflating view with that only. But how can i access in the layout xml? So that i can set visibilty directly there

Comment: `View#setVisibility`

Comment: I know can do that from Java code. But, I want to access it in layout file using data-binding.

Comment: how are you inflating your xml view?

Comment: `ListItemContentMainBinding viewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.list_item_content_main,
                    mBinding.splitFriendsContainer, true);`

Comment: so you have `ViewDataBinding`, whats the problem with it then?

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with that. I want to it in xml layout file. If you have noticed there is a line in EditText `android:visibility="@{btn3.checked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"` This is what I want to achive. Through data-binding and not in Java code.

Comment: Because, on changes to the checked state, it can dynamically change the visibility of `EditText`. That's the purpose of data-binding. Get off the code from Java to layout files for the views. If I have to do that type of calls like `setVisibilty` and `setText`, I won't be using data-binding then. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: @pskink Can you show me how to do it as an answer?

Comment: What is radio_type element ?

Comment: `radio_type` is id of `RadioGroup`. However, I got this working with a different solution. By populating selected radio button's id with my pojo and that pojo is also passed to all manually inflated layouts. So whenever checked radio button changed, I change my pojo, and it updates all underlying manually inflated layouts. I will post detailed answer soon.

Comment: I have made the answer, I am not sure is this the thing you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found a little bit tricky solution for your problem. I use few core process of the data binding generation process(https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)  to achieve your problem.

1. Generated Binding Class in binding data (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#binding_data)

> By default, **a Binding class will be generated based on the name of the
>   layout file**, converting it to Pascal case and suffixing "Binding" to
>   it. The above layout file was main_activity.xml so the generate class
>   was MainActivityBinding.

Which means the same time you add the layout tag into the xml, the corresponding Binding class is also created.

2. Use View ids to get the final instance of the view(https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#views_with_ids)

> **A public final field will be generated for each View with an ID in the
>   layout**. The binding does a single pass on the View hierarchy,
>   extracting the Views with IDs. This mechanism can be faster than
>   calling findViewById for several Views.

Instead of putting the instance of the binding to the included layout, try to make a boolean variable for trigger to make the solution to be more flexible.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_type"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/btn_1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="btn_1"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="btn_2"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="btn_3"/>

        </RadioGroup>

        <include layout="@layout/inside"
            bind:numberEditShown="@={btn3.checked}"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

inside.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable
            name="numberEditShown"
            type="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    </data>
    <EditText
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:visibility="@{numberEditShown? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: This code in my hello world is fine. But I dunno why you need to put radioType  reference into the nested layout instead of the radiobutton. I am afraid you might have something else I have not noticed.

Comment: I have a list of items with each item having 2 EditTexts. Based on the selected type, I decide which EditTexts to show. And no of items are decided at runtime, So I manually inflate no of rows, and based on the value of radio type, I need to show or hide the EditTexts.

Comment: Then the above code should work for you, but you need to add one more variable,edittext for your requirement

Comment: Yup, I'll try later and let you know. Thanks a lot